# CI Pagination Offset Not Displaying Correct Values

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi have am new to codeigniter and have been struggling with CI pagination library for days.

I have this app where all pagination are working fine except for skipping data by offset.

i.e. when I click on next, It only shifts data by 1 record only. Example: From 1-10 showing it goes to 2-11 and so on..

Here is my controller:

```
$active = 1;
$total = $this->all_users_model->total_number_of_rows();
$per_page = 10;
$offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

$config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/manage-users/';
$config['total_rows'] = $total;
$config['per_page'] = $per_page;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['num_links'] = $total;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['admin_all_users'] = $this->all_users_model->show_all_user_details($active, $per_page, $offset);
```

Model:

```
public function show_all_user_details($active,$per_page,$offset) {
    $this->db->where(array('activated'=>$active,'admin !='=>1));
    $this->db->limit($per_page,$offset);
    $this->db->order_by('api_id','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get('registered_members');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your offset is incrementing only with one at a time: `page/1`, `page/2`, also as your db query limit. Currently, your db limit is `$this->db->limit(10, 1);`, `$this->db->limit(10, 2);`.

**This shows 10 records from record 1, and then from record 2.**

Just change the limit in your model to:

`$this->db->limit($per_page, $offset * $per_page);`

Comment: Thanks for reply @lamzozo.. Yes that solves my problem but only other thing which is happening now is that pagination starts work from 3rd page only.. Example if I have per_page = 5 then in page 1(default page) it shows record from 85-89.. But when clicked on NEXT or page 2 it shows records form 73-77.. And after there it shows exact records like 68-72, 63-67.. so on

Comment: Yepp, its because the limit has to start from zero, and then 5, and then 10. But the uri segment for the pagination is 1, 2. So: `0*5=0`, then page 2 `2*5=10`. Just change the offset line to `$offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? ($this->uri->segment(3)-1) * 5 : 0;`. Notice that I made multiple here by **5**, so you don't need to multiply in your model!